# If you have an Android XML layout and you need to change only 3 things (2 textViews and 1 icon) what do you think is the best solution?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a xml layout for displaying some results, depending on the result type I need to adjust this view changing 2 textViews and one ImageView, the rest of the layout keeps without changes.

The solution I think is the best is to change the text and the image inside my java code (programmatically).

A friend suggests that is better to make a copy of the entire layout and change this 2 text labels and the image.

IMHO that leads into duplicated code that is why I do not think this is the best option. What do you think is the best approach ? Do you think of a better one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of change are you talking about ? Value or Orientation ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam about value.

Comment: Programetically set image resource and text in your textview based on your result in java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction. Using 2 different layouts for different results will be absolutely redundant. You can set `TextView` values by :

`textView.setText("Your Text")`
 and Image resource *programatically* by:

`imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);`  according to your result.